# Chrome automatically refresh on css/less change

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, less, google-chrome-devtools

I want to automatically refresh chrome immediately after an change of my less files. For some reason chrome can not even read my less file. So i always need to wait until the lessc have created my .css file. There a tools out there that are checking resources for changes and reload the page. I've even written my own: [Luba Autoreload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/luba-autoreload/pbkdhjjigfmmodacjodghoioeglbmieo). What i annoying is the waiting time between less compiles and the extension request resources to detect changes. Chrome DevTools seems do not solve the problem as well. After mapping my style.css to a network resource i always need click inside the source in chrome to refresh for some reason (no auto reload).
I really prefer a way to immediately detect a less change and reload the browser. I can write a solution but i do not can spend all my time in stuff like these. Maybe somebody have an idea. Maybe there a solutions for Firefox ? I'm also using a prefixer, but i think i can forget it in this context.

Comment: Please take a look at https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors

Comment: Works for me just by klicking to chrome back /reactivate window with the soruces

Answer (score 0):

Use [LivePage](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pilnojpmdoofaelbinaeodfpjheijkbh) extension. It supports LESS also. It also works offline and for file:// too. 

EDIT:
Increase the refresh duration to 1000ms in LivePage's option page. It may help you. And don't select the option for "Entire Domain". It will monitor whole domain and will slow down your system, if you have many files in your domain. Use LivePage for the file, or files you are currently working on.

Comment: It crashes everythime after an refresh. I use my solution for now.